# Attempting to implement a while loop breaks the code

Tags: python, csv

I have been playing around with a dataset attempting to better learn how to code with Python.

The code I have created works perfectly, but only for one row of a CSV file (I have 571 rows of data). This takes the row and then compares the first number with the second number, depending on if the first number is bigger or smaller it will put that number into the corresponding list. The code then moves on to the next value and does the same thing.

```
bigger = []
smaller = []
mL_ind = 1
add = 0
add_s = 0

gross = []
largest_val = []
net_total = []


initial = open('output.csv')
reader = csv.reader(initial)
mathLine = [line.split(',')[1] for line in initial]
del mathLine[0]
mathLine = list(map(float, mathLine))

for value in mathLine:
    if value > mathLine[mL_ind]:
        bigger.append(value)
        mL_ind = mL_ind + 1
    elif value < mathLine[mL_ind]:
        smaller.append(value)
        mL_ind = mL_ind + 1

for value in bigger:
    add = value + add

for value in smaller:
    add_s = value + add_s

total = add - add_s
gross.append(total)

largest = max(mathLine)
largest_val.append(largest)

net = total / largest
net_total.append(net)
```

What I was attempting to do was use the index (after line.split) from: mathLine = [line.split(',')[1] for line in initial]
to work as an iteration for moving through the CSV file, as well as being the counter for my while loop. However, when I set this up I get an error for this line: if value > mathLine[mL_ind]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: could you attach the error message, thanks

Comment: Here is the error message: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: try `mL_ind = 0` instead of `mL_ind = 1`

Comment: I have the mL_ind as one, as that is what sets the comparison up. Value is the first number, mL_ind is the second number for the greater or less than.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me...

import csv

```
bigger = []
smaller = []
mL_ind = 1

add = 0
add_s = 0

gross = []
largest_val = []
net_total = []

initial = open('dummy.csv')
reader = csv.reader(initial)


mathLine = [line.split(',')[1] for line in initial]

print (mathLine)


del mathLine[0]
mathLine = list(map(float, mathLine))

for value in mathLine[:-1]:
    if value > mathLine[mL_ind]:
        bigger.append(value)
        mL_ind += 1
    elif value < mathLine[mL_ind]:
        smaller.append(value)
        mL_ind += 1


for value in bigger:
    add = value + add

for value in smaller:
    add_s = value + add_s

total = add - add_s
gross.append(total)

largest = max(mathLine)
largest_val.append(largest)

net = total / largest
net_total.append(net)

print (net_total)
```

Comment: I tried that, and the same error came up: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Fixed, see my updated answer to access the list from the second element instead of the zeroth element (since you deleted the zeroth element).

Comment: maybe `for value in mathLine[:-1]`

Comment: Here is the code with the changes you suggested, and how I am attempting to set up the while loop:
count = 1

while count < 3971:
    count += 1
    initial = open('output.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(initial)
    mathLine = [line.split(',')[count] for line in initial]
    del mathLine[0]
    mathLine = list(map(float, mathLine))

    for value in mathLine[:-1]:
        if value > mathLine[mL_ind]:
            bigger.append(value)
            mL_ind += 1
        elif value < mathLine[mL_ind]:
            smaller.append(value)
            mL_ind += 1

Comment: I am still getting this error: if value > mathLine[mL_ind]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Skates_McFarlin, why do you want the first element in the list deleted using del mathLine[0]?

Comment: The first element in the list is a header that does not need to be used for calculations

Comment: Also, just to be clear @Skates_McFarlin, you want the while loop to break at 3971?

Comment: @K.Land_bioinfo yes that is correct as that is the length of the mathLine

Comment: @Skates_McFarlin, I'm not completely understanding what you are trying to do. If you copy and paste the code I wrote in my edited post, it should loop through the entire length of your mathLine list, therefore, a while loop might not be needed, unless you wanted to break it at a more specific parameter.

Comment: Just updated my post to reflect the full code that is working for me to my best knowledge of what you want to do. @Skates_McFarlin please see my edit and let me know!